# How to split command by & && || ; and | in php that will work with quotes

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I have this function to validate command in php?

```
public function validate_command($command) {
    if (isset($this->config->settings->guest_commands)) {
        $commands = $this->config->settings->guest_commands;
    } else {
        $commands = array('echo', 'cat', 'ls', 'find', 'cd', 'grep', 'test', 'xargs');
    }
    $cmd_re = "(" . implode("|", array_diff($commands, array("xargs"))) . ")";
    if (in_array("xargs", $commands)) {
        $re = "/^\s*($cmd_re|xargs\s*$cmd_re)/";
    } else {
        $re = "/^\s*$cmd_re/";
    }
    $separators = "/(&&|\|\||\||;)/";
    $parts = preg_split($separators, $command, null, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
    $result = array();
    foreach ($parts as $part) {
        if (!preg_match($re, trim($part)) && !preg_match($separators, $part)) {
            $last = array_pop($commands);
            $message = "guest user can only execute: " .
                     implode(", ", $commands) . " and " . $last;
            throw new Exception($message);
        } else if (preg_match('/(>|`|\$\()/', $part)) {
            throw new Exception("guest user can't use redirect to write to files" .
                                " or execute subshell");
        } else {
            $result[] = $part;
        }
    }
    return implode($result);
}
```

it splits command using:

```
    $separators = "/(&&|\|\||\||;)/";
    $parts = preg_split($separators, $command, null, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

How can I make it work for commands like `echo "&copy;"`? it should return the same command but it throw exception.

Can I use single regex with look behind? How it should look like? It should work with cases like this:

```
echo "&copy;\"&copy;" && echo "&copy;"
```

`$parts` should have `array('echo "&copy;\"&copy;"', '&&', 'echo "&copy;"')` (the spaces around && or commands can be included)

I've try `$separators = "/(?<![\"'](?:[^\"']|\\[\"'])*)(&&|\|\||\||;)/";` but got exception:

```
preg_split(): Compilation failed: lookbehind assertion is not fixed length at offset 24
```

Is iterating over the string the only option?

Comment: That preg_split() error is because of this `[\"'])*` part in lookbehind. Lookbehind are [zero length assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). You cannot add quantifiers to them.

Comment: You want to treat `&copy;` as `&`? Replace it then. Or add `&copy;&copy;` to the regex pattern.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew want to ignore split regex if it's in single or double quotes.

Comment: So, match them and skip - prepend your regex pattern with [`(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*')(*SKIP)(*F)|`](https://ideone.com/i9YAsE)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it works, yu can add an answer but I've used `"/1(?:\"(?:[^\"]|\\\")*\"|'(?:[^']|\\')*')(*SKIP)(*F)|(&&|\|\||\||;)/"`

Comment: See revo's answer, I think it will work the same (but it is more efficient than your pattern). I simplified the regex in the comment to just showcase the approach. `\K` will not omit the match, it will return an empty match, but `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` will remove these empty matches.

Answer (score 3):

You should match everything between quotes then exclude them from result set:

```
$re = <<< 'RE'
~(?:"[^"\\]*(\\.[^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(\\.[^'\\]*)*')\K|(&&|\|\||\||;)~
RE;

$str = <<< 'STR'
echo '"&co\"py;"'
STR;

var_dump(preg_split($re, $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(17) "echo '"&co\"py;"'"
}
```

Comment: what is `\K` in regex?

Comment: It forces engine to reset parts of string which are matched so far from output. See [`\K` match resetter](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/regex/1338/match-reset-k#t=201704280823386969309)

Comment: I should mention `(&&|\|\||\||;)` can be reduced to `(&&|\|+|;)` if you know three consecutive pipes or more wouldn't be possible to come in commands.

Comment: I don't know how it should work with `|||`. I think it would be better to just use `\|{1,2}`

Comment: it return wrong results for sting `echo "&copy;\"&;" "&& rm" && echo ls`

Comment: What should be the desired output?

Comment: it should return 3 elements: `['echo "&copy;\"&;" "&& rm"', '&&', 'echo ls']`, same as Wiktor solution.

Comment: So you need to exclude consecutive quoted arguments as well: `~(?:\s*(?:"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(\\.[^'\\]*)*'))+\K|\s+(&&|\|{1,2}|;)\s+~`

Comment: I've decide to use @WiktorStribiżew solution it's much shorter, it fit into one line in my code.

Comment: what edge cases, can you give example that will fail with Wiktor regex and will work with yours? Maybe I should use yours instead.

Comment: Like it won't match escaped quotes inside quotes of the same type.

Comment: What about my modified regex: `"/(?:\"(?:[^\"]|\\\")*\"|'(?:[^']|\\')*')(*SKIP)(*F)|(&&|\|‌​\||\||;)/"` it have `"(?:[^"]|\\")*"`

Comment: Considering regex of matching double quoted strings, [it doesn't match properly](https://regex101.com/r/dnwKDg/1).

Comment: Yea but it matches `"&copy;\\\\"&;"` too while it shouldn't.

Comment: your last regex return single element array for string echo "asd \"asd" && rm it should return ['echo "asd \"asd"', " && ", 'rm']

Comment: That's not about regex but how PHP `preg_split` works. [**You should add a flag**](https://3v4l.org/HOu27). I'm not sure about your PHP level, but accepting and unaccepting an answer for several times is not a good idea and violates professional ethics. *Ask before judging if you don't know how things work.*